# Same query in different database context gives different result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

The following query, when executed in `AdventureWords` and `tempdb`, will give different results.

```
SELECT  o.type_desc,
        OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id) name,
        definition
FROM    [AdventureWorks].sys.sql_modules m
        INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id;
```

When you execute it in the `tempdb` context, the `name` column will be NULLs, not the real object name.
What's the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `OBJECT_NAME` looks at objects in the current database as specified by a `USE` statement; change your call to specify the specific database you want object information for:

```
OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id, DB_ID('AdventureWorks')) AS [name]
```